# Combining duplicate entries with missing data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have what is hopefully a simple problem for someone.

I have many entries and some of them have duplicate Team_ID values.

In essence, imagine someone keypunched new data into a table without looking to see if it existed already (this is a hypothetical example).

Here is the data (note Team_ID 1 and 2 repeat):

```
Team_ID Items_sold  Total_Sales Team_Size   Profit
   1       40           280         NULL     NULL
   2       32           192         NULL     NULL
   3       56           336         4        NULL
   4       23           161         6        NULL
   1       NULL         NULL        5        NULL
   2       NULL         NULL        6        100
```

from script:

```
SELECT TOP 10000 [Team_ID]
      ,[Items_sold]
      ,[Total_Sales]
      ,[Team_Size]
      ,[Profit]
  FROM [JEC].[dbo].[Small_Try$]
```

I want the data to look like this at the end:

```
Team_ID Items_sold  Total_Sales Team_Size   Profit
   1       40           280         5        NULL
   2       32           192         6        100
   3       56           336         4        NULL
   4       23           161         6        NULL
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Please specify your DBMS.

Comment: Should Team_ID have multiple values for any reason, or it should be unique?

Comment: sorry  SQL Server 2014.  As for multiple team values, they should be unique in nature.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
 SELECT TOP 10000
  [Team_ID]
  ,MAX(ISNULL([Items_sold],0))
  ,MAX(ISNULL([Total_Sales],0))
  ,MAX(ISNULL([Team_Size],0))
  ,MAX(ISNULL([Profit],0))
 FROM [JEC].[dbo].[Small_Try$]
 GROUP BY [Team_ID]
```

This is asuming that you want the max value in case of collision. You could use any group function like sum, min (with proper ISNULL value), etc

Edit:

```
SELECT TOP 10000
 tg.[Team_ID]
 ,(SELECT t1.[Items_sold] FROM [JEC].[dbo].[Small_Try$] t1 WHERE t1.[Team_ID] = tg.[Team_ID] AND t1.[Items_sold] IS NOT NULL) as Items_sold
, (SELECT t2.[Total_Sales] FROM [JEC].[dbo].[Small_Try$] t2 WHERE t2.[Team_ID] = tg.[Team_ID] AND t2.[Total_Sales] IS NOT NULL) as Total_Sales
, (SELECT t3.[Items_sold] FROM [JEC].[dbo].[Small_Try$] t3 WHERE t3.[Team_ID] = tg.[Team_ID] AND t3.[Items_sold] IS NOT NULL) as Team_Size
, (SELECT t4.[Profit] FROM [JEC].[dbo].[Small_Try$] t4 WHERE t4.[Team_ID] = tg.[Team_ID] AND t4.[Profit] IS NOT NULL) as Profit
FROM [JEC].[dbo].[Small_Try$] tg
GROUP BY [Team_ID]
```

I think this should work now

Comment: Hi Emi1305,  The actual data has varchar(), float() and int() values and some are negative.  so I don't think this will work.

Comment: John, I've just edited it, try it now. The new query won't work if you have multiple not null values in any of the columns for any Team_ID

Comment: Emi, this worked after I replaced 0 with NULL.  I have over 160 variables, is there an automated way to change the script or do I have to type each one out.  Thanks again

Comment: John, you should use dynamyc sql. But I never used it in sql-server, I can't help you there, sry. 
Edit: Aslo if you mean the NULL inside the ISNULL function, you can just take out that function and it will be faster

Answer (score 0):

Using dynamic SQL to aggregate:

```
declare @sql varchar(max) = 'SELECT TOP 10000
  [Team_ID]
'

select @sql = @sql + ',MAX(' + QUOTENAME(name) + ') AS ' + QUOTENAME(name)
from [JEC].[sys].[columns]
where object_id = object_id('Small_Try$')
and name <> 'Team_ID'

set @sql = @sql + 'FROM [JEC].[dbo].[Small_Try$]
 GROUP BY [Team_ID]'

EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: when I run this all I get isTeam_ID
1
2
3
4

Comment: @John Edited. You have to exclude Team_ID from the list of column names created dynamically. Try as is now

Comment: still have same issue, only thing displayed is the data for Team_ID

Comment: @John do the other fields show up with null values, or the query only returns one column?

Comment: Thx Sam, only returns one column

Comment: @John Change `EXEC(@sql)` to `print @sql` and let me know what it prints out

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using SQL Server 2014 (2012 would have been enough), you can make nice use of [`FIRST_VALUE()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213018.aspx). The idea is that for each column, you pick the first value, and in the `OVER()` order clause you use the column itself in a descending order. That way, any non NULL value will come before NULLs and will be picked. Whenever all values are NULL, you'll get NULL. If you use the `DISTINCT` modifier, you'll only get one row per team:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Team_ID,
  FIRST_VALUE(Items_sold) OVER(PARTITION BY Team_ID ORDER BY Items_sold DESC),
  FIRST_VALUE(Total_Sales) OVER(PARTITION BY Team_ID ORDER BY Total_Sales DESC),
  FIRST_VALUE(Team_Size) OVER(PARTITION BY Team_ID ORDER BY Team_Size DESC),
  FIRST_VALUE(Profit) OVER(PARTITION BY Team_ID ORDER BY Profit DESC)
FROM [Small_Try$]
```

You can see how it works live on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/56580/2). I've separated the last row to 2 parts so you see how it functions when more then 2 exists, and notice that the Profit column is `varchar()`, and still works.